# vBulletin archive rewrite rules on Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, vbulletin

I got a problem for `vBulletin` archive running on `Nginx 0.8.54`. The `Nginx` gives me `404 error` when I try visiting the following URLs

http://mydomain.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-19.html
http://mydomain.com/forums/archive/index.php/f-19.html

All other things of `vBulletin` works fine. Can anybody may share its rewrite rule to fix my problem ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
                        location /archive               {

                                                            rewrite ^/archive/index.php/t-([0-9]+)\.html /archive/index.php?t-$1.html last;
                                                            rewrite ^/archive/index.php/f-([0-9]+)\.html /archive/index.php?f-$1.html last;
                                                    }
```